# How do i insert imageA into the same table row as logo,using the same id using PDO

Tags: php, mysql

When I insert imageA, it goes into a new row with a different id. And when I use update, it updates properyly, but I cant seem to keep imageA and logo in the same row using the same id(picID)

Insert logo:

```
if(!isset($errMSG)) {
  $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO pics(logos) VALUES(:upic)');
  $stmt->bindParam(':upic',$logos);
```

insert imageA:

```
if(!isset($errMSG)) {
  $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO pics(imageA) VALUES(:imgA)');
  $stmt->bindParam(':imgA',$imageA);
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `pics` (
  `picID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `logos` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageA` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Edit imageA:

```
if(!isset($errMSG)) {
  $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('UPDATE ulnapics SET imageA=:imgA WHERE picID=:uid');
```

Edit Logo:

```
if(!isset($errMSG)) {
  $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('UPDATE ulnapics SET logos=:upic WHERE picID=:uid');
```

Comment: You already have the code you need.  If you want to update a row instead of inserting a new row, use your `UPDATE` statement.